# How do I create a new user in AD from SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, configuration, active-directory

I am looking to have a SharePoint Extranet Portal setup for my "partner" clients. I want to make a site admin for each extranet site for each client. This admin would be able to add new users to the portal AND have that user be created in AD (Active Directory).

Has anyone done this or know of a good tool that would provide me that ability to do this?

Comment: Do you have an estimate for how many partner clients and users you expect?  We have made these kind of investments but our solution would not make sense for small site.

Comment: Well starting out it is a fairly small client base, however we plan on a full expansion and many clients in the next year or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using ADAM (Acitve Directory Application Mode). This way you separate your own company users. Seeing as it's AD, you can keep your existing authentication provider.

See this tool (costs money though) for creating AD users.

[Bamboo Solutions User Account Setup Web Part](http://www.sharepointreviews.com/component/content/article/50-user-management/98-User-Account-Setup-Web-Part-by-Bamboo-Solutions.html).

DO a Google search for SharePoint and ADAM for more information.

Comment: Once again sir, you come through for me with my SharePoint needs! Thank you

Comment: What about a less expensive route? This solution looks like it would solve exactly what I would like to do, but now I need to try and justify the cost.

Do you or anyone else have any other (cheaper) solutions?

Answer (score 1):

I found these articles on creating users into AD. You could use SmartPart and build your own web part and manage the security implications of this.

Here they are:

http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/1242-Creating-New-User-Account-Active-Directory-usi.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/everythingInAD.aspx

Thanks!